# Why type converter for Room not working? - Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I keep getting an error `[ksp] .../Converters.kt:9: Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods.` Why is my converter not working?

My entity:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class ContentItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    val colorText: Color// Field that I want to convert
)
```

My database:

```
@Database(entities = [ContentItemEntity::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)// Apply converter to entire database
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun contentItemDao(): ContentItemDao
}
```

My converter:

```
...
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.room.TypeConverter

class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromColor(color: Color): Int {// Error message is referring to this line
        return color.toArgb()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toColor(colorValue: Int): Color {
        return Color(colorValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try nullable types (`Color?` and `Int?`) and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Nothing changed. I had to change the color type to `Int` because I could not overcome the error. I have a suspicion that KSP (Kotlin Symbol Processing - Kotlin alternative to Kapt) does not work correctly with some data types (`androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` in my case).

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp and the migration steps, which may unearth the cause.